# How to create virtual column with multiple value using MySQL SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, virtual-column

I can add virtual columns as

```
SELECT '1' as id

| id |
-------
|  1 |
```

But I want add multiple values, example:

```
SELECT ('1','2','3') as id

| id |
-------
|  1 | 
|  2 | 
|  3 |
```

But this don't work

Comment: SELECT 1 id UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3

Comment: you can't have a single query split a single row into multiple rows, but you can have multiple queries, each producing one of the values, by chaining them together with `union`.

Answer (score 0):

Like Marc B said in a comment you can't have a single query split a single row into multiple rows, but you can have multiple queries, each producing one of the values, by chaining them together with union.

```
SELECT 1 id 
UNION 
SELECT 2 
UNION 
SELECT 3
```

As the answer was provided in a couple of comments I'll post it as a community wiki.